# How to decide which research method to be used?

Tags: research, ux-designer, discovery, workshop, discoverability

**Quick summary:** I'm working on a product that provides accommodation booking (hotels, apartments, houses etc). The team wants to implement a comparison module to the property details page which offers other properties to the user in case the current property they are looking is not the right one for their needs.

The team have already created a framework that describes the user journey in each step of the booking process, which was very helpful.

I've already conducted a competitive teardown in order to understand how cross-selling is explored in other travel sites and have already studied previous related researches. I have also collected analytics data and all main findings were presented back to the team.

I'm having some difficulties in deciding what should be done next. I understand that each project is different and it all depends on the user and business goals. However, in a case like this, would it make sense to run a design workshop (like How Might We and crazy 8's) in order to get ideas from the team? If not, what other sorts of activities would you recommend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the nature of the feature that you are designing. To my knowledge, this kind of comparison module is not very common in the accommodation booking domain, but common in other areas like hardware specs or financial instrument comparison. So it's somewhere between a completely exploratory feature vs. something very common.

I think you're on the right track on running a design workshop next. it's important to get the team involved for features like these early on. This ensures everyone feels they contributed and it will help later on as well. Then based on the results i'd suggest pick 2-3 of the best solutions and prototype them in mid-fidelity. then test them on a few users and decide which to iterate ahead with. All the best!

Answer (score 1):

Check this masterpiece article https://www.nngroup.com/articles/which-ux-research-methods/ to get your answer.

Hope this helps !